# How to store last encountered header's id from HTML when traversing the DOM in Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, header

I have a typescript/react app that converts some markdown files to html using marked.js and displays the converted HTML to the web page. In the code snippet below I iterate over text nodes to grab all the raw text values that get displayed to store them in 'searchIndexReference' where a text value corresponds to a numeric id.

**How can I keep track of the most recently encountered header's ID and store it in 'headerReference' for all text values found until the next headerID is encountered? For all HTML elements**

```
let id: number = 1;
let headerIdFromHTML = '';
const headerTags = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6'];

files.forEach(file => {
    // convert markdown content to html using marked.js
    const htmlString = marked(file.markDown);
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlString, 'text/html');
    const walker = document.createTreeWalker(doc, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

    let currentNode = walker.currentNode;
    // gather raw text from every HTML element
    while (currentNode != null) {
        if (currentNode.textContent != null) {
            if (currentNode.parentElement) {
                // only care about h1-h6
                if (headerTags.includes(currentNode.parentElement.tagName)) {
                    // store most recently seen header id, update when new header encountered
                    headerIdFromHTML = currentNode.parentElement.id;
                }
            }
            searchIndexReference.push({ id, text: currentNode.textContent });
            headerReference.push({ id, source: file.source, headerId: headerIdFromHTML });
            id++;
        }
        const nextNode = walker.nextNode();
        if (nextNode != null) {
            currentNode = nextNode;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

My current code works somewhat, but it seems to break on HTML elements with `href` or `<em>` so far. In the example below, the last two elements IDs are not properly fetched.

```
<h3 id="banner">BANNER</h3>
<h1 id="project-name">Project Name</h1>
<h2 id="quick-links-a-nameproject_linksa">Quick Links <a name="project_links"></a></h2>
<li><h5 id="basic-components"><a href="#project_components">Basic Components</a></h5></li>
<h4 id="general"><em>General</em></h4>
```

Expected state of headerReference after reading in HTML above:

```
{id: 1, headerId: 'banner', text: 'BANNER'}
{id: 2, headerId: 'project-name', text: 'Project Name'}
{id: 3, headerId: 'quick-links-a-nameproject_linksa', text: 'Quick Links'}
{id: 4, headerId: 'basic-components', text: 'Basic Components'}
{id: 5, headerId: 'general', text: 'General'}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the expected output from the last html example?

Comment: updated with expected output @JackFleeting

Comment: The `<li> element in your last html isn't closed; can you add the closing tag where it belongs?

Comment: @JackFleeting closed li tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you at least close to where you want to get. Focusing on your sample html and using xpath, it creates an array of arrays:

```js
let headerTags = ["h1", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5"],
  counter = 1,
  headerReference = [],
  hits = document.evaluate("//*", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (let i = 0; i < hits.snapshotLength; i++) {
  let hit = hits.snapshotItem(i);
  if (headerTags.includes(hit.tagName.toLowerCase())) {
    row = [];
    row.push(counter, hit.id, hit.innerText);
    headerReference.push(row);
    counter += 1;
  }
}
console.log(headerReference);
```

```html
<app>
  <h3 id="banner">BANNER</h3>
  <h1 id="project-name">Project Name</h1>
  <h2 id="quick-links-a-nameproject_linksa">Quick Links
    <a name="project_links"></a>
  </h2>
  <li>
    <h5 id="basic-components">
      <a href="#project_components">Basic Components</a>
    </h5>
  </li>
  <h4 id="general">
    <em>General</em>
  </h4>
</app>
```

You will have to modify this to fit your actual files, but it should be a start.

Comment: will this solution work on HTML that has n number of non header elements (like <p>) between the headers in the sample? sorry i should've added some elements in between the headers. basically i want to say "all elements under this header are under header-id-abc until we encounter the next header, then we log that new header id and say all elements after are under new header-id and so forth until next header"

Comment: @xXx_emo_girl_xXx It's hard to tell without seeing exactly what html you are referring to. You may want to post that as a new question.

Comment: this solution does not work in typescript since 'hit' can be null. i [modified](https://paste.ee/p/5DRKW#DbKQSZI_ca7lMLDxQuMF2QfJ8xsYy6Te) what you had just to get the code to compile, but i ended up having to use parentElement since that is the only object with the 'tagName' property. side note... is there a way to NOT use parentElement and get tagName? i dont have a good grasp on the DOM but i find it confusing why i can't call 'currentElement.tagName' but instead need to call parentElement on everything